# Several IE CSS issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Ok I admit I always see people griping about IE (Internet Explorer xx) and I never really complain about it but I realize I may be wrong.  I am a hardcore Chrome user, occasionally I'll open up Firefox for something or to test a view but never IE until the other day.  I opened up IE 8 on a site I am working on and was shocked,  There was so much wrong and I am not blaming IE, I am just getting into doing proper CSS and design, I am more of a backend coder.  So most likely I am just not using proper CSS

So below is an image from IE8 of my project, I have labeled each section that has a problem.

[image]

**1)**
This background should expand the width of the page and it does in Firefox and Chrome.

Here is some CSS for this area

```
#header-wrap {
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 95px;
   background: #F3F3F3 url(../images/layout/blue-spike.gif) repeat-x;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}
```

---

**2)**
This is a navigation unordered list, it should show all the list items in a row, left to right and when it gets to wide it starts a new row of items left to right, it does that in Firefox and Chrome

```
#tag-list li a {
   color: white;
   text-transform: uppercase !important;
   background: #585858;
   padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px!important;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   font: .8em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
   margin: 1px 0px 3px 3px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}
```

---

**3)**
Same code from number 2 but instead of square corners, each link should have round corners, it works that way with Firefox and chrome with the border radius

---

**4**
Same as the header section, it should expand the full width of the page but it does not

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
  background: #444 url(../images/noise-gray.png) center;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  with: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

This is another background image for the fotter that is a zigzag at the top of footer, it does not even show up in IE with this code below

```
#footer-zig-zag {
  background: url(../images/shake-up.png) top repeat-x;
}
```

---

I realize this is a vague question and I do not expect someone to recode the site, hint why I havent added all the HTML.

I am just asking if from the above CSS if anything stands out as being incorrect for it to work with IE.

I was never aware of how bad or different IE is from Chrome and Firefox and I would like to not keep making the same mistakes, I do not care to support IE 100% but I think I can do a little better then my current.

Thank you for any help

Comment: In menus - float the LI, not the A.

Comment: @Diodeus I am using the HTML 5 one <!doctype html> also the float on the LI solved that problem, thank you

Comment: If it works in the modern browsers, but not IE, it's most likely IE and not you. You will always have issues with it not rendering the same as the others (if at all). Yes, IE is as bad as you've heard. But, yes, we do need the html. Preferably a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing it entirely, you're right, it's kinda vague, but off hand,

2) looks like the li are in block display....set them to float:left; display:inline;

3) border-radius isn't supported in ie8. for ie9 you need to add -ms-border-radius; you can find js fixes for < ie9 border-radius support

1) and 4a)  again, hard to tell, but with width:100% and them not covering it, i'm going to assume the ie is reading the parent width as something in correctly. set the parent element to width:100% as well.

you can target ie with conditional comments so you don't mess with your real styles like this:

<!--[if IE]>
<style>
div.parentelement{width:100%}
</style>
<![endif]-->